# How to achieve absolute text position in html css whilst considering scaling?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to solve this problem where I want the text "Sample" and then I want texts "bla1" and "bla2" to the right of text "Sample". I also want them to stay together when someone scales up and down their browser. So 100% and 200% zoom on any browser should not change the relative positioning of the texts. Any help is much appreciated! If javascript can solve the problem, I'll use javascript.

This photo explains what I want

[image]

See the code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZBzmY#anon-login

HTML:

```
<div id="tophead">
  <a href="index.html">
    <h1 class="webHeader">Sample</h1>
    <h1 class="webHeader2">bla1</h1>
    <h1 class="webHeader3">bla2</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tophead {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #00284d;
}

#tophead h1 {
  margin: -2px;
}

#tophead a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00284d;
}

.webHeader {
  top: -50%;
  left: -20%;
  font-size: 180%;
  position: relative;
}

.webHeader2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.webHeader3 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify. It's pretty much impossible to understand what your desired behaviour is, and what's the problem you have.

Comment: The problem is that the text "bla1" and "bla2" are not in level with text "Sample". They are below. If you look at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZBzmY#anon-login

Comment: this photo explains it: https://imgur.com/a/p5kbB @FacundoCorradini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to wrap the `bla1` and `bla2` text in `<h2>` and then use **`display: inline-block`**. No need to use **`position: absolute`**

**[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/wpxWaL)**

```css
#tophead {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #00284d;
  text-align: center;
}

#tophead h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#tophead a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00284d;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.webHeader2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.webHeader2 span {
  display: block;
}

.small {
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="tophead">
  <a href="index.html">
    <h1 class="webHeader">Sample</h1>
    <h2 class="webHeader2">
      <span>bla1</span>
      <span class="small">bla2</span>
    </h2>
  </a>
</div>
```